# Script to replace character in certain column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to replace a period anytime it is entered into column A of my spreadsheet with "/".

For example, if a date was to be entered as 12.20.17 I am trying to have it automatically changed to 12/20/17.

I've tried just using the Format options, but it doesn't replace the period with a slash. I have also tried modifying many different scripts I have found, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Using [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use onEdit trigger as below. The event object `e` has the entered value in `e.value` property. If the edit is in the first column, and the new value is a string, the replacement of dots by slashes is made.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart == 1 && typeof e.value == "string") {
    var newValue = e.value.split('.').join('/');
    if (newValue != e.value) {
      e.range.setValue(newValue);
    }
  }
}
```

Be aware that if someone enters 4.6.2017 there is a good chance they mean the fourth of June rather than the sixth of April; simply replacing the separators does not resolve the underlying issue of inconsistent date formats.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked great! Apologies for the incorrect tag as well

Answer (score 1):

First you split all the values which have dot between them into an array

`12.20.17'.split('.') //will be ['12','20','17']`

Then you join array's value and add bettween them `/`

`'12.20.17'.split('.').join('/') //will be '12.20.17'`

Comment: Please elaborate? How would I use this for any date that is entered? And how would I enter this into a script?

Comment: In this case pal, you have to use events.

Comment: @Joe This is why you should tag your questions about Google Apps Scripts with [google-apps-script]. The [javascript] tag explicitly excludes those questions.

Comment: @ Crazy Ivan - Okay, my apologies. I see it has already been changed too, thank you!